# function work just one time but not the second (i have to referesh the page)

Tags: javascript, api, async-await

I created two boxes with translator function, the first translates from native language (Italian) into a recovered language depending on the login on the application; the second from the language retrieved from the login on the application to Italian;
[boxes looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX8IN.png);
the first box has id=#message, the second one id=#message_lang;

For do that I'm using the DeepL API.
The purpose is to use the first one box for write/get the text in italian.
The second box is for write in a others languages with the purpose to get the translated text (in italian) in the first box but also for get translated text from italian.

I used two arrows buttons where each of them has a function:
left arrow translate from language X to italian;
right arrow translate from italian to language X;

```
 btnTranslate_left.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let fromLang = getTargetLang(langToTranslate)
        let toLang = getTargetLang(1);
        translateHandler(fromLang, toLang, box_b, box_a);
    });

    btnTranslate_right.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let toLang = getTargetLang(langToTranslate)
        let fromLang = getTargetLang(1);
        translateHandler(fromLang, toLang, box_a, box_b);
    });

    const getTargetLang = (langToTranslate) => {
        return languageData[langToTranslate];
    }

    async function translateHandler(fromLang, toLang, inputSource, inputDestination) {
        const translatedText = await translate(inputSource.value, fromLang, toLang);
        inputDestination.innerText = translatedText;
    }

    async function translate(textToTranslate, fromLang, toLang) {
        const API_URL = `${ConfigJson.apiDeepLUrl}auth_key=${ConfigJson.apiDeepLKey}&text=${textToTranslate}&source_lang=${fromLang}&target_lang=${toLang}`;
        const response = await fetch(API_URL);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.translations[0].text;
    };
```

***getTargetLang***
provide to convert the id lang into initial of language ex:
1=>"IT",
2=>"FR",
ets,ets

**translate**
it provide to translate the text given into a specific language(DeepL);

**translateHandler**
it handle the translate function response and if the response is in italian, that will be put inside the first box; otherwise the translated text will be putting inside the second box.

**THE PROBLEM**
the functions works every time from italian to X language but from X language to italian it works just one time but after I have to refresh the page.I have not error in the console. What it can be?

I tried to remove async/await but without success.
I don't understand what the problem can be.
thank you very much!

Comment: async function translateHandler(fromLang, toLang, inputSource, inputDestination)  - have this return a value, rather than set 'inputDestination'

Comment: @ThisGuy but i have this error:  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Comment: OK, are you aware of console.log()? you can use it to try and trace out what your functions are doing, what values are assigned, etc.

Comment: Yes. i put console.log() of api response inside translate() function, and i see correctly the response.  But in the eventListener('click'), i see the promise in console.log

Comment: change your function to async function translateHandler(fromLang, toLang, textToTranslate){ //code here } - this allows you to separate data from view. you can then test that function by calling it with what ever you want from the console via translateHandler('italian', 'english', 'buongiorno') - it will then return just a string. you can check this in debug or assign it to a field, as you see fit.

Comment: OK, great. just keep tracing it out to see where the error is introduced

Comment: @ThisGuy but translateHandler is already a async function

Comment: change the input parameters. you currently have a "from ui field" and a "to ui field", change it to "text to translate" and return the translated text from the function. then assign it to the ui field

Comment: @ThisGuys but all is working, the problem is that i can't use the translator from italian -> X language and after the x languages -> italian. For do that, i have to refresh. I can use all the time i want ita -> x language or x language -> ita, but not both of them without refresh

Comment: I can only suggest that most of coding is maintenance and bug fixing. if you employ spaghetti code, then it is very difficult to sort out and even more difficult to work as a team.  I'm sure that you will get some answer to your question, but as it stands, it is difficult for me to understand the workflow and where the issue is, so I can't help any further. hopefully someone else can help you sort this out. I am suggesting that you separate your data from your view, this is a good practice and habit to get into. K.I.S.S. principle applies. Best of luck to you.

Comment: @EnricaS you need to trace down the whole flow. You can use dubugger or simply try console logging each step from button click to api call to setting element value. Hope you will find some lead.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing the HTML elements of the boxes; the error was generated by the `innerHTML` or `textContent` method associated with the `textarea` or `input`; Such boxes do not have these methods/properties. By associating the `.value` to the boxes, the problem has been solved.
Thank you all for the advice!